# How to get an average int for a Collection of an Entity using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have an Employee Entity that has a Collection of Reviews, each Review has a byte grade.

Unnecessary details are omitted for brevity

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "employee",  cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Review> reviews;
}
@Entity
public class Review extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    private Byte grade;
}
```

How can I get an average Review grade for each Employee using Thymeleaf to insert in Table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thymeleaf has [aggregate functions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#aggregates).  You can combine them with [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-collection-projection).

```
<span th:text="${#aggregates.avg(employee.reviews.![grade])}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to add the corresponding method to the class:

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "employee",  cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Review> reviews;

    public double getAverage() {
        return reviews.stream().map(Review::getGrade).mapToInt(Byte::intValue).average()
    }
}
```

and then just call it in thymeleaf

`<span th:text="${employee.getAverage()}" />`